# .Net Core 3.1 Web API Throwing 404 on new Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've created a new controller in a brand new web api project in .net core 3.1.  Whenever I try to post to the route I get a 404.

The controller is set as so:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class AuthCodeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationContext _context;

    public AuthCodeController(ApplicationContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
    public JsonResult GetAuthCode(AuthCode authCode)
    {
        try
        {
            var theCodes = _context.AuthCodes.ToList();
            var tmpCode = new Random();
            var myNum = tmpCode.Next(100000, 999999999);
            while (theCodes.Any(tc => tc.AuthCodeRnd == myNum))
            {
                myNum = tmpCode.Next();
            }

            if (authCode.AuthCodeRnd > 0)
            {
                var removeCode = _context.AuthCodes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.AuthCodeRnd == authCode.AuthCodeRnd);
                if (removeCode != null) _context.AuthCodes.Remove(removeCode);
            }

            Guid authGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

            var tmpRec = new AuthCode
            {
                Guid = authGuid,
                AuthCodeRnd = myNum,
                Address = authCode.tAddress,
                SmallLogoAddress = authCode.SmallLogoAddress,
                ClientFolder = authCode.ClientFolder,
                CompanyFolder = authCode.CompanyFolder,
                Folder = authCode.Folder
            };

            _context.AuthCodes.Add(tmpRec);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            var retVals = new AuthResponse
            {
                Guid = authGuid,
                ReturnAuthCode = myNum
            };

            return Json(retVals);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var message = new ErrorResponse();
            message.Status = "An Error Has Occured";
            message.Message = ex.ToString();
            return Json(message);
        }            
    }
}
```

When I POST to this method I receive a 404.  I'm using the url `https://localhost:44328/AuthCode/GetAuthCode`

The only modifications I made in the startup.cs are adding the dbcontext service options. Everything else is default.  I can get the weatherforecast to show.

EDIT - added startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddControllers();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Solved: I needed to disable SSL Verification in POSTMan

Comment: What routing have you set up in `Startup.cs`?

Comment: added my startup.cs

Comment: Your request is wrong.... When you decorate a controller with ApiController it will behave differently ignoring the Method Name.

Comment: I needed to disable SSL Verification in POSTMan

Comment: 1. Don't call post methods with the prefix `Get` Get will preassume `Get` its not the bug but its ambigious
2. Are you sure you're posting from a form e.g `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 3):

You should set attribute: `[HttpPost]` → `[HttpPost("GetAuthCode")]` since your original route will be simple POST to 'https://localhost:44328/AuthCode'. Core Controller does use reflection to Your Controller name 'AuthCodeController' to form prefix for Your path ('/AuthCode' part). But it does not use reflection to form postfix from function name - You should form it yourself by parameter in HttpPost attribute.

Comment: Please expand on your answer.  This is the correct answer.

Comment: Expanded. Thank You.